# Gcloud Vision API Error opening Cloud Storage File

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-vision, vision-api

I'm trying to run Vision API **Document Text Detection** on a **Firebase Cloud Storage** file. But I'm getting this error:

```
  code: 7,
  details: 'Error opening file: gs://some-name.appspot.com/UsersUploadedFiles/2kuqctFfY0d0sF7ImcDk7Ci2MJo2/questions.pdf.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
```

I've passed the **service account credentials** via environment variables and I'm calling the vision API from `nodejs` like this:

```
const inputConfig = {
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',
        gcsSource: {
          uri: 'gs://some-name.appspot.com/UsersUploadedFiles/2kuqctFfY0d0sF7ImcDk7Ci2MJo2/questions.pdf',
        },
      };
      const outputConfig = {
        gcsDestination: {
          uri: 'gs://some-name.appspot.com/TranscribedData/2kuqctFfY0d0sF7ImcDk7Ci2MJo2/',
        },
      };

      const features = [{ type: "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" }];
      const request: any = {
        requests: [
          {
            inputConfig: inputConfig,
            features: features,
            outputConfig: outputConfig,
          },
        ],
      };

      const [operation] = await client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request);
      const [filesResponse] = await operation.promise();
      const destinationUri =
        filesResponse.responses[0].outputConfig.gcsDestination.uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. The issue was that the GCloud Vision API and the Firebase project were two different projects.

There was a slight name difference between these two project, that's what messed up this for me